# Mysql single table very slow

Tags: mysql

I have a single InnoDB table in MySQL containing 50+ columns. In the table there are over 500000 rows. I only use a DATETIME column (`dt`) and a VARCHAR(245) column (`code`) for searching. I created an index for both columns.

The following query is fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE `code` IN ('name1', 'name2') LIMIT 0,1000
```

This is also fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE `dt` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND  '2014-12-01' LIMIT 0,1000
```

But combining both takes minutes:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE `code` IN ('name1', 'name2') AND `dt` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND  '2014-12-01' LIMIT 0,1000
```

Can somebody explain me why the last query takes very long while the two first queries are superfast?

The output of explain for the last query is:

```
Select type: Simple
Type: Range
possible keys: dt_index, code_index
key: ts_index
```

Comment: Do you have 2 seperate indexes or a combined one? What is the `explain select ...` output?

Comment: two separate indexes. Here is the explain output:
Select type: Simple
Type: Range
possible keys: dt_index, code_index
key: ts_index

Comment: Add the output to the question please

Comment: Create a composite index containing both columns.

Comment: That did it!! Creating a composite index solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will only use one index and since neither of your two indexes hold values for both criteria it potentially have to scan lots of rows to find 1000 that matches. I think it could potentially be as fast as the first query if your date interval was big enough, say between 1970 and 2015.

To fix it you can add a index covering both columns (and drop the now unneeded one one)

```
alter table TABLE add index dt_code_index (dt, code), drop index dt_index;
```

or

```
alter table TABLE add index code_dt_index (code, dt), drop index code_index;
```

Answer (score 1):

It was fairly simple. I needed to add a composite index to the table as suggested by xQbert:

```
create index fast_index ON traces (dt, code);
```

Now all 3 queries run fast.